# k-fold cross validation of glmnet group predictions

Tags: r, prediction, glmnet

I have a set of predictors that are partially correlated and I would like to reduce them to a functional set and use the reduced model for prediction. I am able to find a good lambda to use by using the

```
> require(glmnet); require(glmnetUtils)
> cvfit <- cv.glmnet(
+         SpeakerGroup ~ Age +transient_mean +syllablerate+syllablerate_sd+intensitysfraction_mean + NucleusPercentVoiced_mean +NucleusPercentVoiced_sd +OnsetPercentVoiced_mean + OnsetPercentVoiced_sd +Shim + Jitt +intensityslope+rateslope + APQ3 +APQ5+DDP_A+RAP +PPQ5 +DDP, nfolds = 20
+         ,family="binomial",data=curr.df,type.measure = "class")
> 
> plot(cvfit)
```

(see image here: https://umu.box.com/s/9rt60v3btfo8qhz870vludv6whxlgfx0 
imgur is not working for me).

```
> cbind(coef.cv.glmnet(cvfit, s = "lambda.1se"),coef.cv.glmnet(cvfit, s = "lambda.min"))
20 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                                  1           1
(Intercept)               -1.229948 -0.84290372
Age                        .         .         
transient_mean             .         .         
syllablerate               .        -0.31636610
syllablerate_sd            .         .         
intensitysfraction_mean    .         .         
NucleusPercentVoiced_mean  .         .         
NucleusPercentVoiced_sd    .         .         
OnsetPercentVoiced_mean    .         0.01119326
OnsetPercentVoiced_sd      .         .         
Shim                       .         .         
Jitt                       .         8.09912574
intensityslope             .        -1.68472631
rateslope                  .         .         
APQ3                       .         .         
APQ5                       .         .         
DDP_A                      .         .         
RAP                        .         .         
PPQ5                       .         .         
DDP                        .         .         
>
```

Ok, this model gets me a set of predictors that I would like to evaluate the accuracy, specificity and so on in terms of predicting group membership (two possible groups).

```
> require(resamplr) # https://github.com/jrnold/resamplr
> # compute 5 folds that have the same balance between groups as the original data set
> curr.df %>% group_by(SpeakerGroup) %>% crossv_kfold(k=5,stratify=TRUE) -> folds
>
```

I may compute the model

```
> folds <- folds %>% mutate(model = map(train, ~ glmnet(
+         SpeakerGroup ~ Age + transient_mean +syllablerate+syllablerate_sd+intensitysfraction_mean +NucleusPercentVoiced_sd +OnsetPercentVoiced_mean + OnsetPercentVoiced_sd  + Jitt +intensityslope + APQ3 +DDP_A,data=.,family="binomial")))
```

(you can find the resulting `folds` object here https://umu.box.com/s/ktxbba4ptzf3hke8g5ze6qgvt0rv42fp)

Now, I want to predict based on each model and the test data set up by the 5-fold procedure.

```
> 
> predicted <- folds %>% mutate(predicted =map2(model, test, ~ predict(.x, data = .y,type="response",s=cvfit$lambda.min)))
```

my I gen an error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: argument "data" is missing, with no default.
```

I am confused by this, as I have provided a `data` argument.

Any ideas of what could have gone wrong here?

Is there a simpler way to get a standard 2x2 confusion matrix of a 5-fold cross validation of a GLMNET model??

Thanks!

Fredrik

Comment: As for the error - you're over-complicating something with dplyr syntax. This is where simple loop would do very good. Second, model is irrelevant. You can calculate any metric at any threshold value given the predictions. Also, heads up that `cv.glmnet` already does the cross validation within the model.

Comment: It seems that there is some issue with the `glmnet.formula` from `glmnetUtils` that  works less well with `purrr::map`.

Comment: But you're right - cv.glmnet does do cross k-fold cross validation. The issue then is how I can extract the fitted values. I need them in order to study the distribution of prediction errors.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comment above, the `cv.glmnet` procedure is a cross validation already. The issue is that I saw no way to extract the fitted values from the model.

For future reference, this works

```
cvfit <- cv.glmnet(
        <description of model>... ,type.measure = "auc",keep=TRUE)
```

The main point is the `keep=TRUE` which allows you to extract parameters later.

```
currInd <- match(cvfit$lambda.min,cvfit$glmnet.fit$lambda)
# There is also a 'cvfit$lambda.1se' to have a look at 
  cutoff <- 0.5
  predicted <- cut(as.numeric(cvfit$fit.preval[,currInd]),c(-1000,cutoff,1000),labels=<your labels> )
```

which gives you a vector of predictions, using your cutoff value, that you can then compared to the actual value.

I do wish that there would be a standardized way of doing this without extracting parameters by hand, but there it is. At least this works.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your question "Is there a simpler way to get a standard 2x2 confusion matrix of a 5-fold cross validation of a GLMNET model?", you can do this fairly simply through the `caret` package as illustrated below. The code also outputs specificity, accuracy etc as requested.

Disclaimer: the code was been modified from "[A short introduction to the caret package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/vignettes/caret.pdf)"

```
library(caret)
library(mlbench) # for the Sonar dataset
data(Sonar) #response is "Class"

# Split data into test and train
train_inds = createDataPartition(y = Sonar$Class, p = .75, list = FALSE)
X_train = Sonar[train_inds, ]
X_test = Sonar[-train_inds, ]

# Fit model using 5-fold cross validation to get optimal alpha and lambda
ctrl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5)
fit  =  train(Class ~ ., data = X_train, method = "glmnet",
              preProc = c("center", "scale"),
              trControl = ctrl)
fit # print optimal values of alpha and lambda

# Get confusion matrix for test data (as well as specificity, accuracy etc)
yhats <- predict(fit, newdata = X_test, type = "raw")
confusionMatrix(yhats, X_test$Class)
```